# React Native FlatList flickers lazy loading additional data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a fairly basic FlatList component implemented using hooks. The list simply loads data from a random user API and lazy loads additional data via infinite scroll. The only visual issue I'm experiencing is that when I merge the new data with the current, the new data being appended flickers very briefly before fully rendering. Not sure what could be causing this.

[image: flatlist flicker]

[Expo Snack](http://snack.expo.io/@johnborges/044274)

```js
const useRestApi = (url) => {
  const [ data, setPeople ] = useState([]);
  const [ page, setPage ] = useState(1);
  const [ results, setResults ] = useState(20);
  const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchPeople = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      const response = await fetch(`${url}&page=${page}&results=${results}`);
      const json = await response.json();

      if(page !== 1)
        setPeople([...data, ...json.results]);
      else
        setPeople(json.results);
      setLoading(false);
    }

    fetchPeople();

  }, [page]);

  return [{data, loading, page}, setPage, setResults];
}
```

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {

  const [{ data: people, loading, page }, setPage, setResults] = useRestApi(`https://randomuser.me/api?&seed=ieee`);

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList 
          data={people}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} 
          renderItem={({item, index}) => (
            <View key={index} style={styles.listItem}>
              <Text style={styles.listItemHeader}>{item.name.first} {item.name.last}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.listItemSubHeader}>{item.location.country}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.listItemBody}>{item.location.street.number} {item.location.street.name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.listItemBody}>{item.location.city} {item.location.state} {item.location.postcode}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          refreshing={loading}
          onRefresh={() => {setResults(20); setPage(1);}}
          onEndReached={() => {setResults(5); setPage(page + 1);}}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => ItemSeparatorComponent}
          ListFooterComponent={() => loading ? ListFooterComponent : null}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: are you able to create barebone version on https://snack.expo.io/ that replicates the issue?

Comment: @Rikin let me try

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@johnborges/044274

Comment: I didn't notice on the expo version. by the way I guess maybe you want to add `results` to `useHooks` dependencies.

Comment: If I comment out `onRefresh` prop then the issue goes away. I see it is also setting couple state, may be that's the cause of it to have list jump, not sure though

Comment: Whats even stranger is that I modified the hook in a separate snack to use a different API endpoint and the issue goes away.

Comment: I also tried removing the `onRefresh` prop and i did notice the list is a lot smoother scrolling, but flickering is still there.